# Алгоритм 2 и 3 числа

Tags: алгоритм

Можем ли мы с помощью определенного сложения 2 и 3 получить любое число, кроме 1 и 0?

```
Пример:
2+2+3=7
3+3+3+2=11
```

Comment: Да. *(12 символов нужно...)*

Comment: Любое число больше 7 (8 и далее) можно представить как сумму 2 и 3 как минимум двумя разными способами. И чем больше число, тем больше способов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да. Любое число (больше трех) отличается от двух на `2n` или на `2m + 3`.

Пример.

```
100 - 50 двоек.
101 - 49 двоек и тройка.
102 - 51 двойка.
103 - 50 двоек и тройка.
```

Comment: А можно пример с его работой?

Comment: @Flashdim а что там пример то приводить?) Четное число - все двойки, нечетное - (n-1) двоек, где n - частное деления на 2, и одна тройка

Answer (score 4):

```
void get(unsigned int n)
{
    switch(n%3)
    {
    case 0:  cout << n << " = 3*" << (n/3) << endl; break;
    case 2:  cout << n << " = 3*" << (n/3) << " + 2" << endl; break;
    case 1:  cout << n << " = 3*" << (n/3-1) << " + 2*2" << endl; break;
    }
}
```

Аналогично можно для двоек - я просто пытался минимальным количеством представить...

```
void get2(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n%2 == 0) cout << n << " = 2*" << (n/2) << endl;
    else cout << n << " = 2*" << (n/2-1) << " + 3" <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно двойку представить с помощью 2. И все числа 2 + 2n с добавлением числа два. То есть можно все чётные числа. Дальше тройку можно представить числом три. И все числа 3 + 2n с добавлением числа два. Число 3 + 2n = 1 + 2(n+1) это значит, что все нечётные можно. Если можно чётные и нечётные , то это значит все начиная с два.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно доказать по индукции.
База:
Можно получить числа 2 = 2, 3 = 2, 4 = 2 + 2.

Переход: n-3 -> n при n > 4
Действительно, если мы могли получить n - 3, то можем получить и n, добавив одну тройку.